# Verification of untypical scriptSig

Tags: p2sh, validation, input-script

I want to be able to redeem a P2SH output with a script doing a multisig but also additional checks. The `scriptSig` to redeem this output thus has to provide enough signatures, as well as some specific data, that is then compared to what's in the redeem script. To my understanding, a `scriptSig` like this cannot be constructed using `signrawtransaction`, but needs to be put together manually. But then it's very prone to errors... Is there still an easy way to check the correctness of this self-constructed scriptSig? Like a RPC call to the verifying function, a miner would call, when validating the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are able to create the raw redeeming transaction yourself, it is possible to pass a signed transaction to bitcoin core's `signrawtransaction` (or `signrawtransactionwithwallet` on new releases), along with a json to describe the utxo being redeemed, to verify correctness.

In this example I'm setting up a json for redeeming a `p2wsh` scriptpubkey that has the very simple, single opcode redeemscript `CHECKSIG`, where the **input's** amount is one BTC.  The input's txid in this example is just `FFFF...FFFF`.

```
'[{"txid":"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"0020EE6BB86B44339392BAE631C8F61DD8F009243C635ADAB33C0B20923A2794BF22","redeemScript":"AC","amount":1}]'
```

I've built the raw transaction redeeming this utxo, which is :

```
02000000000101FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000FDFFFFFF01F0B9F505000000002321027777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777AC0347304402203333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333022055555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555550121030EFF833692060EB20ABF63FDE930AD0F59BFDDF3FAD321AA5C85435120306FD101AC00000000
```

To check the validity of this spend, pass both the utxo and transaction to bitcoin core's `signrawtransactionwithwallet` :

```
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' 02000000000101FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000FDFFFFFF01F0B9F505000000002321027777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777AC0347304402203333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333022055555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555550121030EFF833692060EB20ABF63FDE930AD0F59BFDDF3FAD321AA5C85435120306FD101AC00000000 '[{"txid":"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"0020EE6BB86B44339392BAE631C8F61DD8F009243C635ADAB33C0B20923A2794BF22","redeemScript":"AC","amount":1}]' | bitcoin-cli -stdin signrawtransactionwithwallet

{
  "hex": "02000000000101ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000fdffffff01f0b9f505000000002321027777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777ac0347304402203333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333022055555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555550121030eff833692060eb20abf63fde930ad0f59bfddf3fad321aa5c85435120306fd101ac00000000",
  "complete": true
}
```

To check the correctness of your script, simply replace the relevant values in the utxo and build the spending transaction.
The situation is a bit more involved when validating constraints such as relative and absolute timelocks.  To have extra assurance, you could use Regtest and Testnet to try out your scripts, and even then, if the script is *very* exotic (maybe using undefined op_nop codes, or other forms of non standard-ness), the transaction be easily redeemable on regtest\testnet but at the same time almost impossible to redeem on mainnet.